# Copy paste values within two different 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, 2d, tetris

Say I have this 2D array set up that shows the rotation state of the current Tetris block. How would I go about pasting these values into another bigger 2D array at any specified position? In this case the piece array is four blocks wide and tall, with a map that's ten blocks wide and 20 blocks tall. The value 0 in the example below stands for empty space, and 1 stands for a block piece.

```
// Array of block
        blockMap = new int[4,4]{
            { 0,1,0,0},
            { 0,1,0,0},
            { 0,1,0,0},
            { 0,1,0,0},
        };
```

Comment: Show your efforts at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would write a double loop, copying each value to the larger array, using an offset to position the values. I.e. something like

```
blockMap = new int[4,4]{
            { 0,1,0,0},
            { 0,1,0,0},
            { 0,1,0,0},
            { 0,1,0,0},
        };
var myLargeArray = new int[64, 64];
var offsetx = 3;
var offsety = 4;
// Note: GetLength is slow, so store values before looping
var sizex = blockMap.GetLength(0);
var sizey = blockMap.GetLength(1);
for(var x = 0; x < sizex; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y < sizey; y++){
        // Note: you might want to check if the target indices are valid
        myLargeArray[x + offsetx, y + offsety] = blockMap[x, y]; 
    }
}
```

I usually recommend writing your own 2D-array class that uses a 1D-array as storage, rather than using the build in multidimensional array. The reasons being that it is often useful to have data in a 1D array when interacting with other systems, and that the multidimensional array stores values column-major, while row-major is more common, at least in image processing. But these points are more relevant when dealing with larger amounts of data.